# QNetworkAccessManager::put(): uploading large file

Tags: qt, networking

I am currently working on a sample application which uses QNetworkAccessManager to send the HTTP command. In the sample we are uploading files to server.  Here I want upload the file in chunk by chunk(not whole file).
Is there any way to send large file in chunk by chunk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? With 4.6.x we do proper uploading in chunks for HTTP and HTTPS. In the versions before we had some issues where we re-buffered the upload data in the QAbstractSocket or QSslSocket.

Comment: Well, there is 4.6.2 already. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think put(const QNetworkRequest&, QIODevice *) will read only chunk-by-chunk from QIODevice. If you want to restrict size of chunk you can create own class inhertied from base in that way that readData(..) will pass further limited value of maxSize.